# TypeError: PrintLists() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python

This is my error message:

```
TypeError: PrintLists() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

The output should look like this:

Welcome to the Botany Bay home sales calculator
This program will calculate the average selling price of the homes
sold this past year. It will then determine how many homes sold above
the average, how many homes sold below the average, the highest priced
home and the lowest priced home.

=======================================================================
Botany Bay Home Sales

---

The average selling price is: $119221.29

The number of homes selling above average are:  3

The number of homes selling below average are:  4

The highest selling house was: $155249.00   Owned by: Beufort

The lowest selling house was: $85000.00     Owned by: Swanson

Code:

```
def PrintMessage():
#Welcome Message
    print("Welcome to the Botany Bay home sales calculator")
    print("This program will calculate the average selling price of the homes")
    print("sold this past year. It will then determine how many homes sold above")
    print("the average, how many homes sold below the average, the highest priced")
    print("home and the lowest priced home.")
    print("=======================================================================")
    return


def PrintLists():
#declare local variables
    Prices = ['125900', '115000', '105900', '85000', '150000', '155249', '97500']
    HomeOwners = ['Carson','Smith','Jackson','Swanson','Perry','Beufort', 'Anderson']

    print("Botany Bay Home Sales")
    print("*********************************")

    average = DetermineAverage(Prices)
    AboveBelowAvg(Prices, average)
    DetermineHighest(Prices, HomeOwners)
    DetermineLowest(Prices, HomeOwners)

    print()


def DetermineAverage(Prices):
    average = 0.0
    sum1 = 0.0
    for i in range(len(Prices)):
        sum1 += float(Prices[i])
    #Print average
    average = sum1/len(Prices)
    print("The average selling price is: $%.2f" % average)
    return average

def AboveBelowAvg(Prices, average):
#print the number of homes sold above and below the average
    NumAbove = 0
    NumBelow = 0

    for i in range(len(Prices)):
        if float(Prices[i]) > average:
            NumAbove += 1
        if float(Prices[i]) < average:
            NumBelow += 1

    print("The number of homes selling above average are: ", NumAbove)
    print("The number of homes selling below average are: ", NumBelow)

def DetermineHighest(Prices, HomeOwners):
#Determine Highest priced home and home owner
    highvalue = int(Prices[0])
    index = 0

    for i in range(1,len(Prices)):
        if (int(Prices[i]) > highvalue):
            highvalue = int(Prices[i])
            index = i

#print out highest value and the owner of that house
    print("The highest selling house was: $%.2f\tOwned by: %s" % (highvalue, HomeOwners[index]))

def DetermineLowest(Prices, HomeOwners):
    lowvalue = int(Prices[0])
    index = 0
    for i in range(1,len(Prices)):
        if (int(Prices[i]) < lowvalue):
            lowvalue = int(Prices[i])
            index = i

#print out lowest value and the owner of that house
    print("The lowest selling house was: $%.2f\t\tOwned by: %s" % (lowvalue, HomeOwners[index]))

PrintMessage()
PrintLists()
```

Comment: On what line' is the error message?

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help you when clearly the code that caused the error isn't even present?

Comment: The code works for me! I didn't get any errors!

Comment: This code works for me as well. Are you using the real Python editor or another tool?

Comment: The code works for me in actual python as well, but I am doing an assignment in Zybooks and its giving me that error. I cannot determine what I am doing wrong to get that error for my PrintLists()

Answer (score 0):

You can have everything in one print. You just have to put a `\n` at the end of each sentence where you want to make a break.
Edit:
I just tested your code but didn't get any errors.